# Hadoop and analytics?

Tags: hadoop, analytics

I'm in the process of building a complete 'scale-out'able solution to provide in-depth realtime analytics to our customers.

The customers mainly have up to 200 servers, each having at most 400 sessions ongoing, which gives 80000 sessions simultaneously.
I wish I could provide analytics for the sessions, and use a BI tool for example Tableau to provide the graphics and the querying interface (basically aggregates queries).

I expect each session to be 4 minutes long, and trigger something around 20 events within 4 minutes. Each event could be around 5 fields, mainly integers. I would log start date, end date, and basically some counters during the session (count of clicks for example). This is around 8000 inserts per second.

I though about Hadoop since RDBMS will clearly not be very easy to scale out (will use PostgreSQL if you convince me tha PostgreSQL can handle this load on a 5000-8000$ machine).

However, I've read that Hadoop has too much latency since it is batch oriented, so it might not be suitable for analytics. What do you think ?

What is the solution used by the web marketing industry to feed a database and query it ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 4):

Twitter has open sourced [Storm](http://tech.backtype.com/preview-of-storm-the-hadoop-of-realtime-proce), they call it the `Hadoop of realtime processing`. The [use case](http://engineering.twitter.com/2011/08/storm-is-coming-more-details-and-plans.html) `stream processing` and `distributed rpc` meets the above mentioned requirements. Note that this is not dependent on Hadoop. [Here](http://www.slideshare.net/nathanmarz/storm-distributed-and-faulttolerant-realtime-computation) is a presentation on Storm. Then there are [HStreaming](http://hstreaming.com/technology/hstreaming/) which sits on top of Hadoop, [S4](http://incubator.apache.org/projects/s4.html), [Streambases](http://www.streambase.com/company/).

Plain Hadoop suits batch processing and is not for real time analytics. The above are **some** of the s/w for real time analytics. Some of them sit on top of Hadoop (like HStreaming) and some don't. Some are are free and some are commercial. There are a bunch of variants, based on a detailed requirement study, features supported by the different s/w and finally a proof of concept a s/w can be finalized.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, the core of Hadoop is batch-oriented, which makes it better for periodic reporting, not realtime data analysis.

One option is to use a graphing and logging system dedicated for event processing.  In this case, it seems like a tool like [Graphite](http://graphite.wikidot.com/) would be perfect for your needs.  There is a [post on the Etsy engineering blog](http://codeascraft.etsy.com/2011/02/15/measure-anything-measure-everything/) that describes how this could be used.

If you like Hadoop, you use something that's built on top of Hadoop, such as [OpenTSDB](http://opentsdb.net), which uses [HBase](http://hbase.apache.org).

Comment: Graphite looks good for monitoring, but not for analytic stuff (filters/joins...). Thanks for pointing out anyway !

Answer (score 0):

Its true that hadoop (well map reduce), if for batch processing.
However, hadoop is also a distributed fs system.
As real time data enters your cluster, you can have worker nodes process it as its becomes available.

For example, if you want to update some dashboard every 5 minutes, you can setup a demon that reads from hdfs, all the newly added log files from the individual tracking server, and updates the storage where your web app reads its data.

At the end of the day, using map reduce you will do the same your demmon has done, but this time using all the files of the day, and all the nodes in your cluster.